# Zero Phase Filter implementation in C same as 'filtfilt' function that we have in python scipy library

Tags: python, c, scipy, signals, signal-processing

I have a C implementation of a Biquad filter. I want to do zero phase filtering. For which I am passing the signal in fwd direction first and then time reversing the signal and passing it again through the filter. But I am not getting the correct output.

In filtfilt function in python. They have some initial conditions as well that is calculated using lfilter_zi(b,a), which is being passed as parameter to lfilter function twice in fwd and bwd direction, also some padding is done.

While implementing in C, do we also need to do padding and initial conditions for filter state??
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That's right, you need to set the biquad's initial state properly to reproduce scipy's filtfilt. Otherwise you may get strange output near the edges of the signal. The [scipy.signal.filtfilt documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.filtfilt.html) mentions this paper, which it uses when `method="gust"`:

> F. Gustaffson, [“Determining the initial states in forward-backward filtering”](https://doi.org/10.1109/78.492552), Transactions on Signal Processing, Vol. 46, pp. 988-992, 1996.

Or you can look at [scipy's implementation](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/signal/signaltools.py#L3859) to see how they do it.